# Splitting Subfigure across multiple pages

Tags: subfloats

I want to split a main figure which has four sub-figures in it. I am unable to get solution from the previous posts on the same subject and therefore had to make this post.

Comment: How big are the subfigures? Does each one occupy a whole page, or do two subfigures fit on one page? Which package do you use to create the subfigures in the first place? Since `figure` environments can't be split across pages, have you considered creating two (or even four) separate, stand-alone `figure` environments? (In the legends of figures 2, 3, and 4, you might insert a sentence pointing the reader to the first figure in the group.)

Comment: Welcome to SE! What you try so far? Please, provide MWE.

Answer (score 7):

Probably the following solution is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}[tb]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\hsize}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}   
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\hsize}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{first part of my figure}
    \end{figure}
\clearpage   
    \begin{figure}[tb]\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\hsize}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\hsize}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{second part of my figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Macro `\ContinuedFloat` from package `caption` restore figure number and enable increment subfigures numbers from last subfigure in previous figure .

Comment: how to stop `\ContinuedFloat` ? all my subsequent figures have a continued captioning when I us this macro.

Comment: @ggulgulia, simply remove it. for more information, please ask new question. from your comment it is not clear, what actually is your problem.